# Parsing an uploaded file, returning record of 10 fields for each line

Tags: java, performance, parsing, csv

I have a program that reads a .txt file from a given directory. Each record line contains a data and I am parsing it. I think this is costly with it comes to performance but I might be wrong. Here is the method. How can I improve it to improve performance?

```
currentLine = uploadFileReader.readLine();

while (!isBlankOrNull(currentLine)) {                 
            line++;
            String[] record = parseRecord(currentLine);
     // process the record array here..
}
```

```
private String[] parseRecord(String currentLine){

    String[] recordLine = currentLine.split("\\|");
    String[] record = null;
    String[] zeroArray = null;          

    if(recordLine.length == 4){
        zeroArray = new String[] {"0","0","0","0","0","0"};
        record = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(recordLine, zeroArray);
    }else if(recordLine.length == 5){
        zeroArray = new String[] {"0","0","0","0","0"};
        record = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(recordLine, zeroArray);  
    }else if(recordLine.length == 6){
        zeroArray = new String[] {"0","0","0","0"};
        record = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(recordLine, zeroArray);  
    }else if(recordLine.length == 7){
        zeroArray = new String[] {"0","0","0"};
        record = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(recordLine, zeroArray);  
    }else if(recordLine.length == 8){
        zeroArray = new String[] {"0","0"};
        record = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(recordLine, zeroArray);  
    }else if(recordLine.length == 9){
        zeroArray = new String[] {"0"};
        record = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(recordLine, zeroArray);  
    }else{
        record = recordLine;
    }

    return record;
}
```

Comment: Is that `while` loop right? Either fix it or omit it from the question.

Comment: [Cross-posted from Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33645800/1157100) — please declare cross-postings.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite this more simply as follows. The requirement appears to be return an array of String always length 10 with "0" filling any unused cells?

Without real test data I cannot comment on its relative performance to your original, it does however significantly "less" work, less array allocations, condition checking etc, so is "very likely" to be faster...

```
private String[] parseRecord(String currentLine) {
    String[] recordLine = currentLine.split("\\|");
    String[] record = new String[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < record.length; i++) {
        if (i < recordLine.length) {
            record[i] = recordLine[i];
        } else {
            record[i] = "0";
        }
    }
    return record;
}
```

Test

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseRecord("1")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseRecord("1|2")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseRecord("1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseRecord("1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10")));
}
```

Output

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```